# What is the problem with using IS_MEMBER to test for permission inside a windows forms app?

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I have windows forms app that connects to sql server using connection string (windows auth).

On the form load event I will execute `IF IS_MEMBER('rolename') SELECT 1;` statement using `command.ExecuteScalar()` method of `SqlCommand` class to check if the user belongs to a role. Or `SELECT IS_MEMBER('rolename');`. For example: db_datareader. If the query returns 1 then I will allow user to access the app. Otherwise exit the app. The goal being that only members of this role are allowed to use my app.

What is the problem with this approach? And what is a better solution?

Comment: What do you mean minimum? Every role is configurable and new roles can be made... by default anyone on the same domain can connect and select. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: When I add the windows user to the sql server login and database users list via management console, what is the minimum permission that I must setup for each point from my question?

Comment: you want to connect and select so you have to set the permissions CONNECT and SELECT   or rephrase your question because i still don't get what the actual problem is you are trying to solve.

Comment: What about data_reader role? What is the minimum role.

Comment: it just ocurred to me that your query will never work from C# and it has nothing to do with access rights. IF ELSE blocks can't be used in queries. one workaround is SELECT CASE another is a stored procedure

Comment: IF ELSE query works for me via ExecuteScaler. I am using sqlserver 2019 express edition.  The reason for asking this question is to understand what is the minimum security requirement for a user to be able to run it. My dba gives access using roles so he has asked me what is the minimum role required for a windows forms user to be able to run it.

Comment: @variable why are you trying to as SQL Server for a *Windows* group membership? This smells like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a problem X (restrict access to a specific group? prevent a group?) and assume the solution is Y: manually  check for group membership. When that fails, you ask about Y, not X. What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? You can add and assign permissions to Windows Groups directly. There's no reason to use `IS_MEMBER`

Comment: @variable you can add Windows Groups to database roles so you don't have to hard-code the Windows group names.

Comment: I have not mentioned windows group anywhere. This question is purely related to permissions for windows user on the sql server.

Comment: In any case, it doesn't matter how you execute the query. SSMS is just a client application as far as the database is concerned.  All connections are made using connection strings. `IS_MEMBER` already returns `1` on success, so you could write `SELECT IS_MEMBER(@role)`

Comment: @variable actually you did, because that's what [IS_MEMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/is-member-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) does : `Indicates whether the current user is a member of the specified Microsoft Windows group or SQL Server database role.` You don't need it to check permissions in most cases. You simply assign permissions to the group or role and let the server handle permissions. That's *far* safer than using or  *forgetting* to use `IS_MEMBER` to check for membership

Comment: @variable if you use ADO.NET it means you're on Windows. Why ask the database for your account's group membership? You can check it directly with `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.IsInRole`.

Comment: Is_member(role) - this checks whether user is members of the given sql role. So I am asking what should be the minimum permission on sql server so that user using the windows forms app is able to connect via connection string and the app can fire that select is_membet command.

Comment: Can you help here ?

Comment: @variable I already did. You're asking the same wrong question, over and over. It doesn't matter whether you have a desktop or web app. *Everything* connects using connection strings, so mentioning that doesn't explain anything. There shouldn't be any requirements for an account to check its own roles but then, why use `IS_MEMBER` at all? Have you tried executing `SELECT IS_MEMBER(someRole)`? Did you encounter an error? And again, and again, why not let SQL Server restrict access instead of checking `IS_MEMBER`? That's no security at all. It won't prevent access by a malicious client

Comment: What you mean by let sql server restrict access please?

Comment: Imagine that you are user of my windows app. When you open the app, the form load event has code that will check  if you have data_reader permission in sql server database. So what permission should I give your windows user in sql server? Is assigning only data_reader role enough?

Comment: I mean that you can assign permissions to tables, stored procedures and views so only the users or *roles* that have permission can read or execute anything. There's no reason to check the role. An account that isn't allowed to read from a table won't read from it, period. If that account belongs to a role, like `db_datareader` it will be able to read from tables. There's no reason to check the role. And DON'T USE `db_datareader`! This *bypasses* all permissions allowing the account to read everything.

Comment: I have a requirement to chekc the role. That's the point of this question.

Comment: That's not the requirement, that's how you think it can be done. Again, SQL Server already checks the role before allowing you to do anything.  Did you even try executing `SELECT IS_MEMBER()`? You'll find there's no requirement, because you're checking your own account's role. Simple `public` is enough to run this. That won't protect access in any way though. A user can simply connect directly to the database and execute any allowed SQL command. That's why I say that `IS_MEMBER` makes sense only for display reasons

Comment: In the query you will see that I am doing SELECT IS_MEMBER(ROLENAME) THEN 1. This means that if he is not member of the role then I can call Application.Exit. so only if user is member of that rolename (data_reader in this case) will he be able to open the app.

Comment: Did you understand my response above to `That won't protect access in any way though.`?

Comment: I get your point that anyone can fire SELECT IS_MEMBER.. What I don't understand is - why checking for role name is useless. I have explained my situation in the above comment. Note the query will be executed by c# application.

Comment: And after all these comments and revisions your question is still not clear and a bounty won't improve that. The problem is that you never tell what you're trying to achieve. Yeah, execute a query, check a role. But *why*? Your underlying question seems to be how to authenticate & authorize a user. It's highly uncommon to do it this way.

Comment: Well I just want to make sure that - just because a user is added to database he shouldn't be able to use the app. The user should have atleast db_datareader role.

Comment: Generally a bad idea to give the users windows login permissions in the DB as this means they can access the DB via SSMS and perform undesirable actions or read values which they shouldn't have access to. One option is to add all users who are allowed access to the app to a windows group - myapp-read etc. You can then check this in the app. The windows app could access the DB with a dedicated user (encrypted in a config file). Alternatively allow access to the DB and then use an Application Role using sp_setapprole.

Comment: Why should this be a problem? Who says that?

Comment: you should try like this, is_member has to equals something   IF IS_MEMBER('db_owner') = 1   SELECT 1
   ELSE IF IS_MEMBER ('db_owner') = 0  SELECT 2

Comment: Say I want to test db_datareader. The select statament returns 1 when either a member of db_owner or db_datareader logs in because a db_owner is implicitly a db_datareader also. How can I check specifically membership of db_datareader role?

Answer (score 0):

You can just try a go with Entity Framework and [Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) class.
I used it with a web app but you can surely integrate it with a GUI. You can use Windows Authentication however this resolves to finally paying Microsoft for Azure synchronization so from a financial perspective this solution is mainly for companies that can afford it.
But you can select in-app authentication method. All forms of possible supported authentication forms are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/individual?view=aspnetcore-5.0). I assume you use newest .NET5. If you don't there is "standard" implementation of Entity Framework (not Entity Framework Core).

Answer (score 0):

One thing which the answers have missed so far:

> If the query returns 1 then I will allow user to access the app. Otherwise exit the app.

Wrong behaviour! However you implement permissions in your app the behaviour should not to just simply close the app - at least provide the user with information as to *why* the app will not start for them.

As far as implementation goes, you should ideally use an identity provider such as Azure AD.  I know you mentioned Windows Forms but this code sample (for UWP) should give some idea on implementation: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-uwp-v2

Answer (score -2):

I'm seeing the following challenges with your current approach

1. Both Application and DB Authentication is using Windows authentication, hence when a new user is added you need to provide them with the DB access so that the application can fetch data for those users
2. By doing so, You're giving the Users a provision to access the Database, so if somehow they are able to get Your Server name from somewhere, they can simply connect to your database and manipulate any data as they wish

I would suggest the following changes to overcome the above challenges a well as the current challenge that you have with the Roles

1. Create a SQL User and use the same in the application for connecting the database
2. Define a User, Role, and User Role table Like below

[image]

then instead of assigning Database Roles to the new users, add Roles in these tables and use the below QUery to find if a user is having a valid role

```
SELECT
1
FROM UserRole
    INNER JOIN User
        ON  UserRole.UserId = User.UserId
    INNER JOIN Role
        ON Role.RoleId = USER.RoleId
    WHERE User.UserName = '<Windows User Name>'
        AND Role.RoleName = '<The Role You wish to check>'
```

if the above query returns any rows then the user is having a role in the system and  proceed accodrignly

Comment: But this means I have to hardcode the sql authentication in the app. This is a problem because update to password would require app to be redeployed. Hence I want to use windows authentication for all users. Can you guide me with this approach.

Comment: @variable I would still suggest a One-time re-deployment and have the credentials configurable in the App Config file because in the Long run The Windows Authentication Approach will be hard to manage and will also cause severe Security Threats

Comment: Credentials configured in app configuration will result in app config file on every user's machine and is a big security risk as anyone can open config file and see the credentials.

Comment: @variable is this a web app or a Windows App

Comment: Windows forms app as mentioned in the question.

Comment: then I would say, better to encrypt the config file and deploy it than just deploying

Comment: Doesn't having windows authentication followed by checking sql role make it simpler.

Comment: Windows authentication will make maintenance very difficult, and most importantly, it'll create serious security threats to your application. So the Best , safe and easy method is to convert to SQL authentication and follow the above suggested design

Comment: Assuming I want to use windows auth in sql, then is there anything wrong in the way I am testing the role?

Comment: Then, Still I would suggest the above design, and in the user Table under the user name column, insert the Windows User name and the rest should work as explained abvoe

Comment: Any reason specifically why checking role is bad approach?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236291/discussion-between-jayasurya-satheesh-and-variable).

Comment: This query created by ef core, it looks like what you need.
IF EXISTS
    (SELECT *
     FROM [sys].[objects] o
     WHERE [o].[type] = 'U'
     AND [o].[is_ms_shipped] = 0
     AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
         FROM [sys].[extended_properties] AS [ep]
         WHERE [ep].[major_id] = [o].[object_id]
             AND [ep].[minor_id] = 0
             AND [ep].[class] = 1
             AND [ep].[name] = N'microsoft_database_tools_support'
    )
)
SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0